# How to set radio button by default in angular 4.0?

Tags: angular

I am currently using angular 4.0. I have two radio buttons, how to set some radio button by default.

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 5px;">
         <input type="radio" value="timeShift" (click)="selectOption($event)" ngModel="mValue" > TIMESFTO & TIMESFT1
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 5px;">
    <input type="radio" value="rsh" (click)="selectOption($event)" ngModel="mValue" checked="checked"> RSH1
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 default radioButton Checked by Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780840/angular-4-default-radiobutton-checked-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use value attribute to checked by default.

```
   <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 5px;">
     <input type="radio" [value]="true" 
      (click)="selectOption($event)" ngModel="mValue" > TIMESFTO & 
        TIMESFT1
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 5px;">
    <input type="radio" [value]="true" (click)="selectOption($event)" 
       ngModel="mValue" checked="checked"> RSH1
   </div>
```

Or You need to set value of variable timeShift/rsh in component with boolean true.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[checked]` to make radio button checked

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 5px;">
    <input type="radio" [value]="'timeShift'"   > TIMESFTO & TIMESFT1
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 5px;">
<input type="radio" [value]="'rsh'"   [checked]="true"> RSH1
</div>
```