# Angular how to default set radio buttons, Reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Implementing a reactive form in Angular with radio buttons. I want to set a default value, I have tried the following:

### Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" class="actionsForm">

    <input type="radio" id="entertainCrowdSkill1" [value]="skillsForBackend[0]"
    class="radiobuttons" formControlName="skill" [checked]="true">

    <input type="radio" id="entertainCrowdSkill2" [value]="skillsForBackend[1]" 
    class="radiobuttons" formControlName="skill">

</form>
```

### Model:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      skill: ['', Validators.required],
    });

  }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.controls.skill.value) // logs empty string
}
```

The button appears to be checked even the `CSS:checked` class is applied. However, when I try to log the value of skill it is an empty string (the default value entered in the fb). I have seen an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780840/angular-4-default-radio-button-checked-by-default) but this was for template driven forms.

How do I set a default value for the radio buttons in the template in a reactive form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assign the initial value with the `FormBuilder` group contructor instead of using [checked]. You assigned the value `''`, which is an empty string. To execute the onSubmit function add `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` to the form tag.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="radio" formControlName="skill" [value]="skillsForBackend[0]">
  <input type="radio" formControlName="skill" [value]="skillsForBackend[1]">
</form>
```

In your typescript try the following.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    skill: [this.skillsForBackend[0], Validators.required]
  });
}

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.form.value) // should show { skill: /* your data */ }
}
```

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen I'm not sure why you'd pass `form` or `form.value` to `onSubmit` though. It's basically already available within your component, accessible via `this.form`.

Comment: I think both solutions are ok, passing `form.value` or getting the values by `this.form...`. At least it's both working.

Comment: I do agree that passing form.value is unnecessary noise. Of course it works, but `this.form...` will do the same in the method itself. Less noise. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below method worked for me.

**First add value attribute in your html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" class="actionsForm">

    <input type="radio" id="entertainCrowdSkill1" [value]="skillsForBackend[0]"
    value="crowdSkill1"
    class="radiobuttons" formControlName="skill" [checked]="true">

    <input type="radio" id="entertainCrowdSkill2" [value]="skillsForBackend[1]" 
    value="crowdSkill2"
    class="radiobuttons" formControlName="skill">

</form>
```

And then modify your model as below.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      skill: ['crowdSkill1', Validators.required],
    });

  }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.controls.skill.value) // logs empty string
}
```

Notice how the value of the value attribute added in html is also added as the initial value of the **skill** in form group.