# Radio Button Default checked

Tags: angular

```html
<div class="form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked="checked" name="radio" [(ngModel)]="radio" [value]="true">Actif
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio" [(ngModel)]="radio" [value]="false">Désactivé
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to set the Default checked on radio button but its not working with `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: add your ts code

Comment: i have only return its value true or false

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780840/angular-4-default-radio-button-checked-by-default

Comment: ngModel radio should initialize to true.

Comment: no its not set default check on browser

Comment: Use this code in typescript class. `radio=true;`

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input type radio value can be string, number or boolean.
For default check a radio button the value of ngModel and value attribute of radio input should be equal.

for example.

typescript: `radio=true;`
html: `[value]="true"`

typescript: `radio='ABC';`
html: `[value]="'ABC'"`

typescript: `radio=999;`
html: `[value]="999"`