# How to set radio button selected by default in angular 8?

Tags: angular

I am very new to angular 8 technology and have some problem setting one of the radio button checked by default.

I have tried to add some of these attributes `[checked]="true", checked` but problem is still the same.

HTML

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <mat-radio-button type="radio" id="materialUnchecked" name="filterType" 
        value="0" [(ngModel)]="filterType" [checked]="true">
        By client
    </mat-radio-button>

    <mat-radio-button type="radio" id="materialChecked" name="filterType" 
        value="1" [(ngModel)]="filterType">
        By student
    </mat-radio-button>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

TS

```
protected filterType;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 default radio button checked by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780840/angular-4-default-radio-button-checked-by-default)

Answer (score 10):

Set default value for a variable and use like below
Here I have used flag as the default variable

**TS**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      name = 'Angular';
      flag: any;
      constructor() {
        this.flag = 0;
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="1" id="1" class="with-gap" [(ngModel)]="flag" [value]="0">
<input type="radio" name="2" id="2" class="with-gap" [(ngModel)]="flag" [value]="1" >
{{flag}}
```

This is the stackblitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyy5y8

Answer (score 3):

set filterType value to true in your ngOnInit.

`this.filterType=1;`