# Angular Input type radio doesn't recognize attributes

Tags: html, angular, radio-button

I have a multiple inputs form, all of them are type radio button.
I need to set "required" and "checked by default" attributes, problem is Angular is not recognizing any of these.
Trying to have a default checked item, I've already tried:
using checked, checked=true, checked="true", [checked]="true", [checked]="{1 ==1}" ...

[image]

None has worked so far. And it's the same with "required".

Maybe is there anything I have to do on the TypeScript side?
I'm using Angular 9, more specific @angular-devkit/core": "9.0.6"

Here is a little example of what I'm doing:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tables',
  templateUrl: './perso.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./perso.component.css']
})
export class PersoComponent implements OnInit {
    q1: number;
    
process() {
      console.log(this.q1);
      }
      
      }
```

```html
<form>
                        <div class="row">
                            <p>1. I am the life of the party:</p>
                                <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" [(ngModel)]="q1" required>Very Inaccurate</label>
                                <br><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" [(ngModel)]="q1">Inaccurate</label>
                                <br><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" [(ngModel)]="q1"  checked="true">Neither Accurate Nor Inaccurate</label>
                                <br><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" [(ngModel)]="q1">Moderately Accurate</label>
                                <br><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" [(ngModel)]="q1">Very Accurate</label>
{{'\nValue of q1: '+q1}}
                            <hr>
                        </div>
<button
                                type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right"
                                (click)="process()"
                        >Process</button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780840/angular-4-default-radio-button-checked-by-default did you try [value]?

Comment: @Kimchy Yes, I have used [value] = true and [value] = "true"

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-buttons?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Supercool. Thanks, I've tried the method in the link. In the StackBlitz example:  [checked]="radiobutton === model.option" , the value of "radiobutton === model.option" is *true*, so I'm back to the:
[checked]="true" which, sadly, is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[value]` instead value.

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <p>1. I am the life of the party:</p>
        <label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="q1" required #q1Answer="ngModel">
      Very Inaccurate</label>
        <br><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="q1">
      Inaccurate</label>
        <br><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" [value]="3" [(ngModel)]="q1">
      Neither Accurate Nor Inaccurate</label>
        <br><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" [value]="4" [(ngModel)]="q1">
      Moderately Accurate</label>
        <br><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" [value]="5" [(ngModel)]="q1">
      Very Accurate</label>
        {{'\nValue of q1: '+q1}}
        <hr>
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="q1Answer.errors"
                                type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right"
                                (click)="process()"
                                [innerText]="(q1Answer.errors) ? 'Choose your answer' : 'Process'"
                        ></button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have used [value] = true and [value] = "true", doesn't check the input. And I've considered to give q1 a value in the onInit(), but this is part of a 50+ questions form, it's a bit impractical init all of them, plus that doesn't solve the form being unable to set them as *required*

Comment: @SilviaQuintela Value is not true or false. It should be the values of options. Eg : ``` [value]="1" ``` .  You can disable the button until user select an answer. I have updated the answer accordingly. Check that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really! I didn't understand the suggestion at first, but I did this change, and it's totally working. Thanks again!

Comment: @SilviaQuintela you are most welcome. Please mark the answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Problems is with `ngModel` and `value`. You haven't set a value to `q1` variable so neither radio button `value` attribute matches the value in `ngModel` and therefore neither radio button should be checked. You must give `q1` a value in your component. Also is important to consider that if you have value set like `value="1"` in your html Angular will interpret that as a `string` so `q1` must be also a string in your component like `q1="1"`. If you need to set `q1` to some non-string value you must use `[value]="non-string-value"`  in your html for example `[value]="1" (number)` or `[value]="true" (boolean)`

Comment: Thanks. I have no problems reading q1 value on the component, once a user checks any of the radio buttons, and I've considered to give q1 a value in the constructor or the onInit(), but this example shows one of a 50+ questions form, it's a bit impractical to init all of them, plus that doesn't solve the form being unable to set them as *required*

Answer (score 1):

Hellow, seems like you have to set first default values for the one you want to start checked and use directive ngModel on this way:

```html
<input id="male" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="male" name="gender" [ngModel]="gender" required checked>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="male">Male</label>

<input id="female" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="female" name="gender" [ngModel]="gender" required>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="female">Female</label>
```

and on `component.ts` u can initialize the default values

```js
gender: string = "female";
```

With this sintax required is working too.

I have the code on here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-template-driven-form-utczgn

Wich it's a fork from here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-template-driven-form

Comment: Thanks @Pedro de León. I've visited the link provided but there doesn't seem to be a default checked option visible on the result, even after the code provided the attirbute *checked* in the input line. I guess it's an Angular thing.
PS. But the required part totally works in there

Comment: now it's working, i did'nt updated correctly mb. Its the first link :D